# Set new value for first occurrence of an object

Tags: c#, linq

So let's assume I have the following structure of response:

```json
"TestObject": [
    {
        "Created": "2022-10-27T07:17:30.671Z",
        "Name": "NOTTEST",
        "FlowInfo": {
            "Type": "TESTTYPE",
            "ActionRequired": false
        }
    },
    {
        "Created": "2022-10-27T09:54:54.582Z",
        "Name": "TEST",
        "FlowInfo": {
            "Type": "TESTTYPE",
            "ActionRequired": false
        }
    },{
        "Created": "2022-10-27T09:55:55.582Z",
        "Name": "TEST",
        "FlowInfo": {
            "Type": "TESTTYPE",
            "ActionRequired": false
        }
    }],
}
```

I need to change "ActionRequired" to true for first occurrence in list with "Name"="TEST", all others objects with "Name"="TEST" should stay with false.

Here is my code snippet

```cs
var b = testObject
    .OrderBy(d => d.Created)
    .Where(d => d.Name == "TEST")
    .Select(d => new ObjectFlowInfo {
        ActionNeeded = true,
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Access the first object with

```cs
var b = testObject
    .OrderBy(d => d.Created)
    .First(d => d.Name == "TEST");
```

and set the value with

```cs
b.ActionNeeded = true;
```

This assumes that at least one object fulfills the condition. If the query may return no object then use

```cs
var b = testObject
    .OrderBy(d => d.Created)
    .FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == "TEST");
if (b is not null) { // or   b != null   or   !(b is null)   in older C# versions.
    b.ActionNeeded = true;
}
```

Note that you can simplify `Where(cond).First`/`FirstOrDefault()` to `First`/`FirstOrDefault(cond)`. This is also more performing but has the same effect.

Both `First` and `FirstOrDefault` select the first object if any and return it as is (and not in a `IEnumerable<T>` as would `Select`). If there is no such object, `First` throws an exception whereas `FirstOrDefault` returns the default value for that type. I.e., `null` for a reference type.

Answer (score 1):

It should be as easy as that

```
var b = testObject.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Test");

if (b != null)
{
     b.ActionRequired = true;
}
```

Comment: Except that will throw an exception if there aren't any.

Comment: True I will update it

Comment: Use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Any` and `First`, otherwise you will have two enumerations.